# How do I change the url?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

```
http://www.travelpunk.com/blog/hostel-details/?hname=Jugend+%?+Familieng%C?%A?stehaus+Bregenz&city=Bregenz&date_st=?+Oct+?&date_end=?+Oct+?&num=?&propnum=?&guestnum=?
```

This is my url... i need to change this like as following url

```
http://www.travelpunk.com/blog/hostel-details/Jugend-Familieng-stehaus-Bregenz/Bregenz/&date_st=?+Oct+?&date_end=?+Oct+?&num=?&propnum=?&guestnum=?
```

This is my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

1.How do I make the changes by using .htaccess file?

or

2.Can I make the changes by using java script?

Comment: 1. why do you want this rewrite? 2. Since original URL is served from WP it won't like this change in URL since it works on `REQUEST_URI` 3. Your original URL is throwing all kind of PHP/MySQL errors.

Comment: @anubhava. actually iam not willing to rewrite the url,but client wants to change.

Comment: Since WP is serving content for the long URL therefore it is very difficult to rewrite that.

Comment: thank you anubhava,is there any chance to change that by using urlencode() or preg_replace() methods?

Comment: Unfortunately `urlencode() or preg_replace()` won't help here.